# Azure AD Jwt Bearer token

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I am attempting to build an application with a SPA UI and a web API that uses Jwt Bearer tokens for access control. I can authenticate the user and send the bearer token to the web request,but when I do so I get the following error

> Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: IDX10500: Signature
>   validation failed. No security keys were provided to validate the
>   signature.

I want to the middleware to use the key set found in at

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys

but I am clearly missing something. Below is the snippet of code in my startup to configure the bearer token. Can someone point out where I am going wrong?

```
    var clientId = Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"];
    var tenantId = Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"];
    var issuer = $"https://sts.windows.net/{tenantId}/";

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
       options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
       options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
     })
      .AddJwtBearer(options =>
      {
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.SaveToken = true;
        options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/";

        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = issuer,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudiences = new string[] { clientId },
            ValidateLifetime = true
        };
      });
```

Comment: Have exactly the same issue.

Comment: Looking at the same error, myself.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just fixed this in my code, although I'm still learning how all of this new stuff works. For me, I had to set `IssuerSigningKey` even though `ValidateIssuerSigningKey` was set to `false`. I don't know if any specific value is required, but I set mine to the same value I used when I signed the JWT token.

```
options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidateAudience = false,
    ValidateLifetime = false,
    ValidateIssuer = false,
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("this is super secret")),
    ValidateActor = false
};
```

Comment: It seems to me that you simply disabled token validation. I don't want to use tokens that haven't been validated for fear that people will provide counterfeit tokens.

Comment: That's not necessarily the point. Ultimately, I started validating tokens. It's the fact that IssuerSigningKey wasn't set that was causing me problems.